# failure to initialize SDL audio

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

When i Call SDL_Init passing in SDL_AUDIO_INIT, the function returns a failure.

I called SDL_GetError() but there does not seem to be any message.
I am not having problems getting VIDEO to initialize, only audio. I don't get any errors when compiling. I have linked the SDL mixer library in my makefile.

Here is a minimum reproducible example code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

        //Initialize SDL
        if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO  < 0))
        {
                printf( "SDL VIDEO could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
        {
                printf( "SDL AUDIO could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
                printf("video and audio initialized");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

output: SDL AUDIO could not initialize! SDL Error:

(there is no message for the error)

Here is the makefile

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = 21_sound_effects_and_music.cpp 

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
COMPILER_FLAGS = -g -Wall

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = sdl_program

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I am using the exact code as in the link at the bottom of my post. I installed SDL2 using apt. Programs using only video initialize fine.

Comment: The output is still missing. Please also directly start an online search for that error message. Chances are, someone else already had the problem and solved it. BTW, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO  < 0))` should be `if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)` - watch your parentheses.

Comment: I see that the parens were wrong. Fixing them did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

install libasound2-dev libpulse-dev

and recompyling SDL2

Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss alsa(dynamic) pulse(dynamic) <--- IS OK